# How to open atom using a "atom ." command in terminal?

Tags: windows, cmd, atom-editor

I want to open the project using `atom .` command in command prompt but it says `atom is not recognized as an internal or external command`

How can I fix the problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What base environment? Is it a Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 or a linux like environment say Cygwin? Update the question please.

Comment: Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 @sjsam

Comment: Update the question with the above info please and it is desirable to put the entire command in one line :-) as code. To start try `which atom`.

Comment: You'll need to add atom to your system path.

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Windows, you'll have to go to the enviroment variable select and edit the variable path copy and paste the value down the below.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```

You can do this by opening the run dialog (`win` + `r`), type "SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe" and hit `enter`. Here you should select "Environment Variables..." and edit the `Path` for your user (because atom is probably installed only for you).

Comment: Can you guide to next level ?

Comment: When you added `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\atom\bin` to your PATH and restart your CLI you should be able to use `atom .` as a command

Answer (score 6):

just type in a terminal opened ** - in the right directory - **:

```
atom .
```

*that's all folks!*

Answer (score 3):

**For future reference: Windows user only**

> Go to `C:\Users\<username>`, then enable `Hidden items` in View tab.
> Click `AppData` `Local` then `Atom`. Then, click `app-<version>`.

**Go to the path:**
[image]

> On Search in taskbar type `variable`. Then click `Edit the system environment variable`.
> [image]

> Select `Path`. Then click `Edit`, `New`, and Paste the copied Path [image]. Then finally click all `ok` buttons. Then close cmd and open again.

```
atom --version
```

**To open a project with atom**

> Go to your project directory: by typing `cd /<foldername>` using cmd or bash. Then type,

```
atom .
```

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\atom\app-x.xx.x\resources\cli`, add it to your path. Open cmd, navigate to the desired folder, running the `atom .` command should be functional now

Answer (score 0):

At first navigate to Atom shortcut icon and go to properties there you have to copy the start in address. And after that go to system advanced settings by clicking the This Pc properties or by (win + r) and click environment variables. navigate to the path section and edit the path with the copied address. Boom. Restart your terminal and then see the magic. Check that Images you will get an Idea.

enter image description here